# Deleting AppCompat is giving me vague errors with R

Tags: java, android, build.gradle, android-appcompat

The entire app was working, until I deleted the dependencies piece of code in build.gradle, and changed all references of AppCompatActivity to Activity.

Despite making the changes, some of the times R is referenced for R.id.something it turns red, and says Cannot resolve symbol R. The same thing happened when I tried making a new project, and there seem to be too many solutions for resolving R (like updating the SDK packages, or cleaning/re-building the project, both of which I've tried). This is before and after updating Android Studio.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: This usually means that `R` is not being rebuilt, due to a problem in one of your resources or your manifest. When you try building the project, you should be getting error messages related to the resource/manifest issues.

Comment: is problem solved